# Find the values of $a$ and $b$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Given that the curve $y=ax^2+\frac{b}{x}$ has a gradient of $-5$ at
>   the point $(2,-2)$, find the  value of a and b.

I did this way:
$$-2=a(2)^2+\frac{b}{2}$$
$$-2=4a+\frac{b}{2}$$    x 2
$$-4=8a+b$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{b}{8}$$
But the answer is $a=-1$, $b=4$.

Could you help me out? 
(this chapter is about differentiation of polynomials, power functions and rational functions)

Comment: Algebra error: when you multiply $-2=4a+\frac{b}2$ by $2$ you should get $-4=8a+b$, and if you then divide by $8$, you should get $-\frac12=a+\frac{b}8$. (I would not divide by $8$.)

Comment: You need also to deal with the gradient part. We have $\frac{dy}{dx}=2ax-\frac{b}{x^2}$. When $x=2$, this is $-5$.

Comment: but still can't solve! can you explain more? thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$y=ax^2+\frac{b}{x}$$ $$\stackrel{\text{(2,-2)}}{\implies}-2=a(2^2)+\frac{b}{2}\tag{1}$$

We also have: (derivative)   $y'=2ax-\frac{b}{x^2}\tag{2}$

It has a gradient of $-5$ at that point which means:
$$(2)\stackrel{\text{(2,-5)}}{\implies}-5=2a(2)-\frac{b}{2^2}$$

$$-5=4a-\frac{b}{4}\tag{3}$$

$(1)$ and $(3)$ $\implies$ $a=-1$ and $b=4$

Comment: $-2=8a+b$ and $-5=16a-b$ but still can't get $a=-1$ and $b=4$
sorry about that!

Comment: @SbSangpi: You've got wrong equations. $-2=a(2^2)+\frac{b}{2}$ would be (multiplying both sides by 2) $-4=8a+b$. Do you see how?

Comment: @SbSangpi: The other equation $-5=4a-\frac{b}{4}$ would be $-20=16a-b$ multiplying by 4. Now you should add the two equation: $-20 \color{red}{-4}=16a-b +\color{red}{8a+b}$. Let me know if there are any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

We must have a system of equations to solve for $a$ and $b$. In the above comment, we have the equation $8a+b = -4$ and $16a-b= -20$. By elimination, we have $a=-1$ and $b=4$.

Comment: how did $8a+b=-4$ into $16a-b=-20$?

Comment: The $16a-b=-20$ comes from the gradient calculation, which gives $4a-\frac{b}{4}=-5$. Multiply through by $4$ to clear fractions.

Comment: then where is $8a+b=-4 $ gone?, sorry for my lack of maths.

Comment: We have **two** equations in the two unknowns $a$ and $b$. In simplified form they are $8a+b=-4$ and $16a-b=-20$. To solve, there are various methods. You could use the second equation to get $b=8a+20$, and substitute $8a+20$ for $b$ in the first equation. Or more simply, "add" the two equations. We get $(8a+b)+(16a-b)=-4+(-20)$, so $24a=-24$, $a=-1$. Then use $8a+b=-4$, with $a=-1$, to get $b=4$.